# Изменить данные в tooltip Chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Chart js убрать(изменить на свое), например 1999 в tooltip и оставить только Asia:3700

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [функцию обратного вызова](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) для `title`:

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function() {
                return ''; // Должна возвращать необходимое значение
            }
        }
    }
}
```